# I want to increase the height and width of the svg

Tags: html, css, svg

here the Svg

```
<svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="15">
    <path class="icon-mobile-nav" name="'menu-outline" fill="#242A45" fill-rule="evenodd"
        d="M0 0h18v3H0V0zm0 6h18v3H0V6zm0 6h18v3H0v-3z" />
</svg>
```

I also tried with css but it's not give the expected output

```
.icon {
    width:30px;
    height:40px;
}
.icon-mobile-nav {
    width:50px;
    height:60px;
    fill:red;
}
```

You can also check the link from here: https://codepen.io/nasim67reja/pen/zYwwXMN

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `viewBox` instead of width and height in your SVG, then set your width in CSS

```
<svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 18 15"">
   <path class="icon-mobile-nav" name="'menu-outline" fill="#242A45" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 0h18v3H0V0zm0 6h18v3H0V6zm0 6h18v3H0v-3z" />
</svg>
```

```
svg.icon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

See live example: https://jsfiddle.net/xkqfLhza/1/

See `viewBox` documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox).